# Is there a way to get a two-way connection from client-browser to server application simulating a shell?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, web-applications, websocket

**Problem**

Very short: I want to create Spring Shell, but as a web application.

I want to create a web-application (preferably using Spring Boot), where the frontend (ReactJS) looks like a terminal (or shell), and the backend processes inputted commands. Look at https://codepen.io/AndrewBarfield/pen/qEqWMq. I want to build a full web app for something that looks like that.

I want to build a framework, so that I can develop backend commands without knowing anything about the frontend/web application structure. I basically want to instantiate a "Terminal" object, where I give some kind of input-stream and output-stream. This way I can program this Terminal based on my given interfaces and structure, without the need of setting up all kind of front-end stuff.

A good summary of the question would be: how to send all keyboard inputs to the backend, and how to send all output to the frontend?

The reason I want to create a web application, is because I want it to be available online.

**What I tried**

I think the way of reaching this is using websockets. I have created a small web application using this (https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/25/spring-webflux-websockets-react) tutorial, without the security part. The websocket part is almost suitable, I just cannot get an "input" and "output" stream-like object.

```java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/queue")
    @SendToUser("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message, @Header(name = "simpSessionId") String sessionId) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(sessionId);

        // Do some command parsing or whatever.
        String output = "You inputted:" + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName());

        return new Greeting(output);
    }

    private MessageHeaders createHeaders(String sessionId) {
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor =  SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
        headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
        return headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders();
    }
```

Now with this code, you can parse a command. However, it doesn't keep any "state". I don't know how it works with states and websockets.

I saw you had this Spring Sessions + WebSockets (https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-websocket.html), but this is not really what I want.

I can send a message from the backend to the frontend by using this code:

```java
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/topic/greetings", "hey", createHeaders(sessionId));
```

However, I want my terminal to be able to wait for input commands from the user. Seems like a stretch, but does anybody know how to achieve this?

**What I sort of want**

I basically want other people to program to this interface:

```java
public interface ITerminal {
    void setInputStream(Object someKindOfWrapperForTheInput);
    void setOutputStream(Object someWrapperOfSimpMessagingTemplate);
    void start();
}
```

When somebody opens the web application, they get a dedicated terminal object (so a single connection per user). Whever somebody enters a command in the frontend application, I want it to be received by the terminal object, processed, and response outputted to the frontend.

**Reasons for doing this**

I really like creating command-line applications, and I don't like building frontend stuff. I work as a software engineer for a company where we build a web application, where I mostly program backend stuff. All the frontend part is done by other people (lucky for me!). However, I like doing some projects at home, and this seemed cool.

**If you have any thoughts or ideas on how to approach this, just give an answer!** I am interested in the solution, using the SpringBoot framework is not a requirement. I ask this question using Spring Boot and ReactJS, because I have already built applications with that. A lot has been figured out already, and I think this probably exists as well.
The only requirement is that I can achieve this with Java on a tomcat-server. The rest is optional :)

**Unclear?**

I tried my best to make my story clear, but I am not sure if my purpose of what I want to achieve is clear. However, I don't know how to formulate it in such a way you understand. If you have any suggestions or questions, dont hesitate to comment!

Comment: Does it actually have to be a web application hosted by e.g. your Spring Boot application, or can you launch a secondary process which communicates over another port?

Comment: It makes things more complicated, so rather not. But like I said, if it is a solution I can try it!

Comment: Do a search for `msfvenom` which pretty much sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is a Live Spring shell that shows up in the browser it's fairly simple, all you need is to expose a standard WebSocket via the `WebSocketConfigurer`, then add a `WebSocketHandler` that executes the command and then returns the resulting String as a `TextMessage`.

Firstly the Socket configuration that allows clients to connect to the 'cli' endpoint

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(cliHandler(), "/cli").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public CLIWebSocketHandler cliHandler() {
        return new CLIWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

Then the WebSocketHandler that executes the command. I recommend that for every `@ShellMethod` you specify the return type as `String`, don't use logging or System writes as they won't be returned during the evaluation.

```
@Component
public class CLIWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Shell shell;

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        String result = shell.evaluate(() -> message.getPayload()).toString();

        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(result));
    }
}
```

You can use an extension like [Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en) to test it, by going to **ws://localhost:port/cli**

This is the most basic solution, adding features like security should be easy after this. Notice that I don't use STOMP, because you probably want to isolate users. But it can work alongside STOMP based endpoints, so you can have pub-sub functionality for other parts of the project.

From the question I sense that answer you'd like is something that involved Input and OutputStreams. You could possibly look into redirecting the output of Spring Shell to a different stream then have them forwarded to the sessions but it's probably much more complicated and has other trade-offs. It's simpler to just return a String as the result, it looks better in print outs anyway.